# Does K8s container restart backoff policy kick in on the 1st restart of the container?

Tags: kubernetes

Looked at the K8s documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy

> After containers in a Pod exit, the kubelet restarts them with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s, …), that is capped at five minutes.

Does this mean that there is a backoff of 10 secs on the 1st restart of the container? or does the 10 secs backoff only kickin on the 2nd restart of the container in a 10 minute window?

I see the container enter the CrashLoopBackOff state right after the 1st restart itself. This seems to be inline with the k8s documentation.

```
Args:
      while true; kill -11; done;
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Tue, 14 Mar 2023 14:05:10 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 14 Mar 2023 14:05:10 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
```

Just wanted to double check that this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of events would be like:

The container crashes or exits for some reason.

Kubernetes detects that the container has exited and restarts it immediately.

If the container crashes again within a certain amount of time (which is by default 5 seconds), Kubernetes will wait for a backoff period of 10 seconds before attempting to restart it again.

If the container crashes again, Kubernetes will double the backoff period to 20 seconds before attempting to restart it again.

This process of doubling the backoff period continues up to a maximum backoff period of 5 minutes.

If the container is able to run successfully for a certain amount of time (which is by default 30 seconds), then the backoff period is reset to the initial 10 seconds.

Comment: In my experiment posted above, when Reason =      CrashLoopBackOff, the restart count should have been 2, correct? Why did the container get into the CrashLoopBackOff state when restart count = 1? Maybe I'm misreading K8s CLI output.

Comment: In the code, they say the restartCount is best effort:
"Anyhow, we only promised "best-effort" restart count reporting"
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7adcb3cb37084750ab572a179ba01b9878b8de5f/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/kuberuntime_manager.go#L1281

if you are around when this happens, maybe "k get events" could shed some light. Honestly, I don't remember seeing restartCount: 1 (perhaps it was suppressed by the memory of all the 10xx restarts pods ppl left in clusters I worked on =.=" )